# Unable to access samba file share

Tags: server, permissions, mount, nautilus, samba

Obligatory "new to Linux" (ish) here, but I've recently got a home server set up with Linux/Ubuntu 22, basic nginx server etc etc.

**Context**

A little while ago, I set up a local network share just through the Nautilus GUI, telling it to allow guest users and allow users to edit files. The share consists of my entire user directory, and actually worked immediately when trying to access it from Windows. Ideally I'm trying to set things up so that I have my files shared over LAN so I can do all the things I need from my Windows PC -- This user folder file share again works entirely as intended; files and folders can be viewed, created, edited, and deleted as I please.

[image: Working user folder share]

**The issue**

The issue then enters with my extra drives in the server. I have a Jellyfin server and would like to be able to transfer media files, and initially had the drives formatted as FAT32, tried sharing the whole drive with no success, tried sharing one folder within the drive with no success, tried changing permissions with no success, and after realizing the permissions and tool complications I decided against the headache and re-formatted for ext4.

Nautilus lets me change folder permissions, but not for guests in the "containing files and folders" popout section - no matter if it's run as root or not. Even then, it says other users have read permissions. I once again tried creating a sub-folder and doing the same thing, and this didn't work either. Both my user folder and the drive and its containing folder are owned by the same user: `kit`

Windows shows me this when trying to connect to the second share, but not the first one:

[image: Error]

I have tried a chmod 777 and 755 recursively, neither to any avail. `ll` reveals that the folder has full permissions

Comment: Ubuntu 22?   So you're using Ubuntu Core 22 and not Ubuntu 22.04 LTS; Ubuntu has different products using the *year* (22) format to far more widely used *year.month* format (22.04).  You've tagged `nautilus` which is a desktop app (ie. 22.04 system not 22) where as 22 is server only.

Comment: It's ubuntu LTS. I'm using the desktop environment to make setup a little easier

Comment: Please be precise with details; the 22 system a *specialist* flavor of Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS and is not designed for desktop use at all. In contrast Ubuntu 22.04 is available for desktop or server use. All *year* products have *long-term-support* (10 years) unlike the *year.month* products so LTS is mentioned, but 22 & 22.04 are different Ubuntu products. Apps run confined on 22 so may not see the root file-system, where as not all apps do on 22.04 (*they are different systems so details matter*)

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Please post the output of the following commands:  `testparm -s` ... `net usershare info --long`